# Rails app deployed using Rubber gem - Errors out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have a Rails app running on an instance on Amazon ec2. It is being served via a load balancer.

It was working fine the first time I deployed my app to it. Today I ran 'cap deploy' again. Ever since, I've been getting 504 Gateway Timeout errors.

I can ssh into the instance. I've verified that my deployments are replacing the code in the instance. I also ssh'd to the instance and connected to localhost:80 using telnet. It works, but when I type in 'GET / HTTP/1.1' it returns a 200 Error

I tried to start off by accessing my production logs. But for some reason the production log file does not exist! I checked my config.log_level in production and set it to :debug, to no avail.

I also tried accessing the instance IP address directly, instead of going via the load balancer and still got the same error - which probably means it's not the load balancer at fault.

I have seen a related question here - [Keep getting 504 Gateway Time-out after deploying on ec2 using rubber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398738/keep-getting-504-gateway-time-out-after-deploying-on-ec2-using-rubber)

However, I was not able to make sense of the answer and I'm not sure how outdated it is. If anyone could elaborate or provide an alternate solution or just tips on how to start troubleshooting this, I'd be thankful!

**UPDATE**: 
I did some debugging and explored the logs at /var/log/apache2
That helped me fix a couple of errors. I no longer see the 504 Gateway Timeout. Instead, I see the following error:

```
[ pid=32526 thr=140043323348800 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:862 time=2012-11-01 02:43:06.843 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/mnt/tpot-production/releases/20121031194109': An error occured while spawning the application.
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:294)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:563)

[Thu Nov 01 02:47:41 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

https://gist.github.com/3992814

Comment: Did you check all server references, ie...